# Django - Vista - Modelo

Tags: django

¿Las funciones como por ejemplo registrarUsuario() deben ir dentro de la clase Usuario dentro de models.py o en la view.py ?

otra pregunta , ¿C+ómo hago para usar una función de models.py desde view.py ?

Answer (score 1):

Debe ir en tus vistas, o sea en `views.py`. Lo ideal, según varios libros acerca de Django, es que en tus modelos estén las tablas que usarás y la lógica de tu negocio (`models.py`), en tu archivo de `admin.py`, debe ir todo lo relacionado con el admin de Django, en tus `urls.py` todas tu urls de una app especifica la cual se manda a llamar desde la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto en su archivo `urls.py`,  todos los formularios en tu archivo de `forms.py`, tus pruebas unitarias desde el archivo `test.py`, y lo demás según vayas viendo, middlewares, utils, resources, backends, etc...

Con respecto a tu otra pregunta, si la función no pertenece a una clase, es decir no es un método, o un método estático, simplemente puedes importarla como harías normalmente.

En tu archivo de `views.py`:

```
# en caso que estes posicionado en la misma carpeta que models
from .models import funcion_a_importar
# de lo contrario
from myotherapp.models import funcion_a_importar

# y puedes usarla cuando quieras
...
funcion_a_importar()
...
```

Comment: y si la funcion a usar en view.py es de una clase , como hago?

Comment: si la funcion (metodo en este caso), no es estatica o no es un metodo de la clase, necesitas una instancia de la clase para poder usarla.... es decir si tu clase es `Empleado`, debes tener una instancia `empleado = Empleado.objects.last()` y usar la 'funcion' con el empleado asi: `empleado.funcion_a_ejecutar()`  :D